# Q: Spritekit SKPhysics

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

How can I slide paddles from left to right individually and have the paddle the character jumped on stop while the rest keep sliding? how do I make 4 paddles slowly move to left and right back and forth at the same speed. Please and thank you.

In this code I am trying to make an SKPhysics body for all of them and I don't know how.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    background = self.childNode(withName: "background") as! SKSpriteNode
    jellyghost = self.childNode(withName: "jellyghost") as! SKSpriteNode
    paddle1 = self.childNode(withName: "paddle1") as! SKSpriteNode
    paddle2 = self.childNode(withName: "paddle2") as! SKSpriteNode
    paddle3 = self.childNode(withName: "paddle3") as! SKSpriteNode
    paddle4 = self.childNode(withName: "paddle4") as! SKSpriteNode


    jellyghost.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    paddle1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    paddle2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    paddle3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    paddle4.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
}
```

I am trying to make a SKPhysics body above and I don't how to do that.
and in the code below, I am trying to have each of the 4 paddles move on their own from left to right at the same speed without them moving to the touch and things are not working out for me. right now

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set, with event: UIEvent?) {

for touch in touches{
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    paddle1.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x,duration: 1.0))
    paddle2.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 1.0))
    paddle3.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 1.0))
    paddle4.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 1.0))
}

}
```

I also want to make my character jump to the moving paddles but I don't know how I would make my character jump up by dragging the screen up and releasing it to the current location of the paddle. How would I make it not restricted to not jumping only straight up but be flexible enough to jump x and y. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You will need to give the player and each of the paddles a [SKPhysicsBody](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody) and then use [SKPhysicsContactDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicscontactdelegate) in you scene to detect collisions between the paddle and the player.

When there is a collision between the paddle and the player you can run a func like the one in the example below to stop the paddle if you are moving your player using velocity.

```
func stopPaddle(paddle: SKSpriteNode) {
    paddle?.physicBody.velocity(CGVector(dx: 0, dy:0)
}
```

Please upload your code in future, as it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I edited my question and added details, please give me advice on what to do.